# Is there a function to remove InlineKeyboardMarkup after user has responded? (python-telegram-bot)

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am looking for a way to remove the Inline Keyboard button after the user has responded.
The telegram bot would ask the user to select an option after the user types /default. I want to be able to remove the option for the user to select the response button multiple times.
Below is my sample code, I am using the python-telegram-bot package.

```
list_default_options = ['a', 'b',
                         'c', 'd']

def default_options(update, context):
"""Generates responses for default options."""
button_list = []
for each in list_options:
    button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(each, callback_data=each))
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(button_list, n_cols=2))
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                         text="Choose option",
                         reply_markup=reply_markup)

def build_menu(buttons, n_cols=1, header_buttons=None, footer_buttons=None):
"""
Returns a list of inline buttons used to generate inlinekeyboard responses

:param buttons: `List` of InlineKeyboardButton
:param n_cols: Number of columns (number of list of buttons)
:param header_buttons: First button value
:param footer_buttons: Last button value
:return: `List` of inline buttons
"""
menu = [buttons[i:i + n_cols] for i in range(0, len(buttons), n_cols)]
if header_buttons:
    menu.insert(0, header_buttons)
if footer_buttons:
    menu.append(footer_buttons)
return menu

def query_default_option(update, context):
"""Callback function when inline response is selected"""
print("Default Option: " + update.callback_query.data)
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                         text="Registered: " + update.callback_query.data)

def main():
# Define telegram updater and dispatcher
updater = Updater(token=API_KEY, use_context=True)
dp = updater.dispatcher

# Register handlers

# Different commands or Text
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.command),
                              handle_message))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('default', default_options))
dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(query_default_option,
                                    pattern='^a$'))
dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(query_default_option,
                                    pattern='^b$'))
dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(query_default_option,
                                    pattern='^c$'))
dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(query_default_option,
                                    pattern='^d$'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Edit / Delete Message While Using InlineKeyboard Python-Telegarm-Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511319/how-to-edit-delete-message-while-using-inlinekeyboard-python-telegarm-bot)

Comment: @CallMeStag Unforunately, I am quite new to coding a telegram bot and I am confused by the forum you recommended. Though it does look like it achieves what I am trying to get at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I first linked to another question, but it in fact doesn't quite answer your question and I didn't find other answers which make it more clear, so here we go.

To edit an inline keyboard (read: append a new one or remove it alltogether), the Bot API provides the method [`edit_message_reply_markup`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.edit_message_reply_markup). To append a new keyboard, you have to pass the new keyboard to that method. To remove it, pass `None`.

Note that `python-telegram-bot` provides convenient shortcuts for this,  so that you don't have to worry about reading `chat_id` and `message_id` from the incoming update. So to remove the keyboard, you can e.g. use `update.callback_query.edit_message_reply_markup(None)` or `update.effective_message.edit_reply_markup(None)`, which are equivalent. Please see the docs [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.callbackquery.html#telegram.CallbackQuery.edit_message_reply_markup) and [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.edit_reply_markup). Yo might also want to have a look at the example [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#inlinekeyboardpy).

Also note that there are some more `edit_message_*` methods, most of which also accept an optional `reply_markup` parameter. Not passing that parameter (or passing `reply_markup=None` will remove the keyboard when calling those methods, but if you only want to change the keyboard and leave the rest of the message alone, then `edit_message_reply_markup` is the way to go.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I found this really useful

Comment: update.effective_message.edit_reply_markup(None) is what I searched. Thank you!